# Fetch data from specify just registered user

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have just finished a little mini registration form, where you enter a username, a password, a message and it will insert it into mysql with the following colums:

```
username    password    id  message date    time    country recover_id
```

and these mean:

```
ID = a random generated ID, for later use.

Time = Time of creation
Date = date of creation
Country = empty, later use..

Recover_id = the ID of the registration.
```

After the registration, I do this:

```
        // Let's store these into a session now.
        $username = $_SESSION['user'];
        $password = $_SESSION['pass'];

        //Now let's refresh the page, to a different header.
        header('Location: recover.php?recovery=success');
    }
```

Stored username and pass to a session, and then creating a new header.

and then

```
} 
else if (isset($_GET['recovery']) && $_GET['recovery'] == 'success') 
{
    $fetch = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ':username' LIMIT 1");
    $fetch->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['user']);
    $fetch->execute();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
    echo $row['recover_id'];
    }
}
```

I want to try and go to the specify usernames colum, and fetch information from it, such as recovery_id, or the ID itself.

But this doesn

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\recover\recover.php on line 103
```

I know im doing something wrong, but what?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo)(a very good job there =) ) you can't call `mysql_*` functions.

Use PDO's [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method instead.

```
while($row = $fetch->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
    echo $row['recover_id'];
}
```

---

You need to pass `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` as parameter to be able to retrieve the data using named indexes.

Comment: Thank you!
I get this error:

Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\recover\recover.php on line 100

line 100:

  $fetch->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['user']);

Comment: Your `$_SESSION['user']` doesn't exist.

Comment: But how is that possible? I am creating the session, and then moving headers. + I have session start required.
http://pastebin.com/7NeaGer8

Comment: Where are you setting the session vars? I only see them being accessed.

Comment: @SomeSillyName
   $username = $_SESSION['user'];
   $password = $_SESSION['pass'];

Comment: Oh I get this now, to set a session you have to include the session name first and then do = $variable